# Can I create a stored procedure through bootstrap or through any action in Grails?

Tags: grails

Can I create a stored procedure through bootstrap or through any action?

Comment: <br>I tried only to call stored procedure like this :Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
sql.call "{call My_proc(?,?)}", [params.id.toLong(),Sql.INTEGER],{ delete_status ->
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap this should work:

```
def dataSource

def init = { servletContext ->
   groovy.sql.Sql sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)
   sql.execute("create procedure xyz....")  // returns boolean
}
```